# dotnet core 2 - catch all route? (*menuPath/pageUrl.html)

Tags: c#, routes, .net-core

Is there any way to use routeattribute to create a catch all route?

In my website i have predefined routes like
/cars
/insurances/best

but, since we have a CMS with dynamic menues and page urls, i need a catch all route with endless slashes.

So if i navigate to /whatever/this/is/a/menupath/withapage.html it should go to my Page method. The withapage.html should **NOT** be required.

I tried the following route, but it does not work

```
[Route("{*menuPath}/{pageUrl.html?}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Page(string menuPath, string pageUrl = null, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
```

In MVC 5 we used this setup with GreedyRoute:

```
    routes.Add(
            new GreedyRoute("{*menuPath}/{pageUrl}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Page", action = "Index" }),
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { pageUrl = @"[0-9a-zA-ZøæåØÆÅ+_-]+.html" }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()));

        routes.Add(
            new GreedyRoute("{*menuPath}",
            new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Page", action = "List" }),
            new MvcRouteHandler()));
```

Is there something similar in dotnet core 2?

Answer (score 2):

`{*menuPath}` is a catch-all parameter and it could be used only as the last segment in route template.

I doubt that it's possible to achieve what you want with pure attribute routing. You want to capture the URL part with any number of slashes to one string parameter, but slashes have the very special meaning for URLs and routing. If I were in your place I'd solve it in following way:

```
[Route("{*menuPathAndPage}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Page(string menuPathAndPage, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    var slashPos = menuPathAndPage.LastIndexOf('/');
    var menuPath = slashPos != -1 ? menuPathAndPage.Substring(0, slashPos) : menuPathAndPage;
    var pageUrl = slashPos != -1 ? menuPathAndPage.Substring(slashPos + 1) : String.Empty;

    //  ...
}
```

Well, probably it's not the perfect solution from purist point of view, however this approach should work for you.

Comment: Yeah, i ended up doing that actually. But i think its weird that so few are asking about this. How are people usually generating menupaths and urls?

Comment: I'm working with Web APIs mostly, so I can't answer your question how folks usually solve this for menupaths. Maybe they pass the path as query parameter or have different controllers for different menu paths with some shared base controller class.